# How to fix invalid literal for int() with base 10 error in pandas: "0.75" in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am converting data types of dataframe df2 same as df1 by using below code but it is giving me this error.

code:

```
df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes.to_dict())
```

Error:

`invalid literal for int() with base 10 error in pandas: "0.75" in pandas`

Is there any general solution to fix this line of code?

I tried converting both the data frames values to string but didn't work.

```
df2.astype(str) 
df2 = df2.astype(df1.astype(str).dtypes.to_dict())
```

Comment: What integers should be expected from `0.75` ?

Comment: I think 0 should be fine

Comment: Need convert all float numbers to `0` like `45.0` to `0`? Or converting columns to numeric?

Comment: converting columns to numeric

Answer (score 0):

0.75 is not an integer. Therefore it breaks.

If you want to transform 0.75 to 1, you can round the values and then transform them into integers.

But I guess you should firstly check if that's really what you want to do.

Comment: If I want to convert to 1 using round function or keep it as 0  or I convert them to strings first but where should I apply that function in this line of code?

Comment: Obviously it depends on your data and what column you want to round. https://googlethatforyou.com?q=pandas%20round

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact situation of your dataset because there is no example.

try this one

```
cols = df1.select_dtypes('number').columns
df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give any error but just making sure if it is truncating zeroes or not.

Comment: My code is just code to make your design error free. If there is a problem with result, you should change your design

Comment: It is not giving error but It is truncating the data like I have 1004786.80000001 and this code is changing to 1004786.8

Comment: I just got rid of your error. you make it. your result is made by you.

Answer (score 0):

This one might be perfect if you just wanna mirror data type of every column in df1 to df2.

```
for x in df1.columns:
   df2[x]=df2[x].astype(df1[x].dtypes.name)
```